# A function generating the derivative of f

Tags: python, symbolic-math, derivative, calculus

I´m trying to construct a function that return the derivate of `f`, a function of one variable.

The return value should be a function approximating the derivative of `f'`
using the symmetric difference quotient, so that the returned function will compute `(f(x+h) -f(x-h))/2h.`

The function should start like this:

`def derivative(f, x):`

which should approximate the derivative of function f around the point x. 
Does anyone have a clue what type of code I can use to construct this type of function?

/Alex

Answer (score 2):

For a general function f(x), you can straightforwardly obtain a numerical approximation to its first derivative by the standard (second-order) approximation (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) /2h. The main challenge is to choose h to be small compared to the lenghscale over which f(x) shows non-quadratic variation, but sufficiently large to avoid round-off errors when subtracting nearby values of f(x).

However, if you want an *algebraic* method of differentiating your function, then things are more challenging. The easy cases are where f(x) is known to be a polynomial, so can be represented by a vector of coefficients of powers of x. In that case, [numpy.polyder()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyder.html) can be used to compute the coefficients of the n'th derivative.

For more complicated functions, you may want to look at [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Both the numpy.polyder() and SymPy options require you to represent your function in a way that is specialized to these particular tools. I'm not aware of any method that can take an ordinary Python function and construct another function that implements the *exact* derivative.

Answer (score 1):

what do you want the function to return?
If you want the value of the derivative in a certain x, you probably need three arguments:

```
def derivative(f, h, x):
    return (f(x+h) - f(x-h))/2h
```

if you want to get a function which calculates the above for any x you can use:

```
def derivative(f, h):
    return lambda x: (f(x+h) - f(x-h))/2h
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wan´t the function to generate the general derivative. For example, if f = x^2, the function should return 2x. Not the specific value of the derivative in a certain x

Comment: in that case, you can't use (f(x+h) - f(x-h))/2h which is numeric and can only work if you use symbolic calculation.
Try using Sympy: http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html

Answer (score 1):

Your best best bet would probably be to use SymPy which can do symbolic integration and differentation among other things:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
>>> diff(x**2, x)
2*x
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can define a function f (Example: f(x) = x ^ 2):

```
def f(x): return x ** 2
```

Next using the definition of derivative:

```
def derivative(function, x, accuracy = 20): # The 'Default' of accuracy is 20 and is an optional argument.
    step = 1 / accuracy
    return (function(x + step) - function(x - step)) / (step * 2)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

By the way, I believe this is a typo:

```
def derivative(f, h):
```

Since you are approximating the derivative of function f **around the point x**, it should be:

```
def derivative(f, x):
```

As shown in my code